# open a new text field on selection of any of last 3 checkbox in a Drop Down Multiple Checkbox

Tags: html, css, forms, checkbox, checkboxlist

What I am trying to do here is when any of the last 3 checkbox is selected in this multiple selection dropdown list, I want to display another **text field** which will be the address field. 
What I am doing currently is on a selection of a **Information required** checkbox a drop down list is shown as follows:

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

```
<p id="formSpacing">
  <input id="inforequired" type="checkbox" value="1" 
         onclick="unhide('hidden-input', this)">
  <label for="inforequired" class="iconic link"> Information requested</label>
  <div id="hidden-input" style="display:none">

  <select title="Information Requested" multiple="multiple" 
          name="infoRequested" size="5">
      <option value="option1">options1</option>
      <option value="option2">options2</option>
      <option value="option3">options3</option>
      <option value="option4">options4</option>
      <option value="option5">options5</option>
      <option value="option6">options6</option>
      <option value="option7">options7</option>
      <option value="option8">options8</option>
      <option value="option9">options9</option>
      <option value="option10">options10</option>
  </select>

  </div>
</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically, using jquery the the easiest way to do this was to run a function if an option was clicked which then checks if the value is above 7 (isolating the last 3)

Here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KKMuu/1/

and here is the code used.

I added a text input field for the adress just for example:

```
<p id="formSpacing">
  <input id="inforequired" type="checkbox" value="1" onclick="unhide('hidden-input', this)">
  <label for="inforequired" class="iconic link"> Information requested</label>
  <div id="hidden-input" style="display:none">

  <select title="Information Requested" multiple="multiple" 
          name="infoRequested" size="5">
      <option value="option1">options1</option>
      <option value="option2">options2</option>
      <option value="option3">options3</option>
      <option value="option4">options4</option>
      <option value="option5">options5</option>
      <option value="option6">options6</option>
      <option value="option7">options7</option>
      <option value="option8">options8</option>
      <option value="option9">options9</option>
      <option value="option10">options10</option>
  </select>
    </br>

      <input id="adressinput" type="text" value="Adress Input" style="display: none;"/>

  </div>
</p>​
```

The the Javascript, (using jquery)

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#inforequired").change(function () { $('#hidden-input').toggle(); })                                  


$('option').click( function() {
var num = $(this).attr("value").replace('option','')
    if (num > 7) {$('#adressinput').show(); }
    else
    { $('#adressinput').hide(); }

});
```

if you don't have it referenced already, you will need to reference jquery in your head like so:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: The above code works perfectly on jsfiddle but when implemented on my web page the address field doesn't show up :( Any pre-requisite?

Comment: there is no pre-requisite to this, remember to source jquery before the code as this method requires jquery to run. (see last line). Other than that, without seeing the issue live I cannot say what is breaking it.